# Kubernetes Jenkins Plugin Question about pipeline syntax

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have questions about an example from [Kubernetes Plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin):

```
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.8.0', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Get a Maven project') {
            git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin.git'
            container('maven') {
                stage('Build a Maven project') {
                    sh 'mvn -B clean install'
                }
            }
        }    
     
    }
}
```

1. According to the explanation the git clone is done from default container - `agent-bound`, NOT by the master so how the container has an option to run git command?
2. How container `maven` has an option to compile code from other container? what actually happens by               `container('XXXX')`?
3. I'm working with subversion, after i installed subversion plugin, I have an option to checkout from subversion within the pod pipeline, so I don't understand how plugins on master are available on `agent-bound` container?

Answer (score 0):

if you will not specify a container the step will run in the "defaultContainer" specified; if have not specified it then the agent-bound/jnlp is the default (You can change it too by changing the property) and that does have "git" cli in it so that's why your checkout command works.

All the containers inside POD share a "workspaceVolume".

In your case all your container "agent-bound", "maven" and "golang" will share this workspace volume

so when you fire a mvn command it runs in the "workspaceVolume" which already has the code from the previous checkout step.

Comment: I'm working with subversion, after i installed subversion plugin, I have an option to checkout from subversion within the pod pipeline, so I don't understand how plugins on master are available on agent-bound container?